# Polychoric Corelation -- When to use?

Tags: correlation, polychoric

I'm analyzing a survey that contains self ranking? Would I use polychoric correlation to compare these scores to nominal variables such as gender?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Gender is categorical, not nominal (e.g., masculine, feminine, non-binary, agender—possibly others—and individuals who occupy more than one of these categories).

Comment: My bad, I meant sex, and only as an example.